# How to make my web URL available for both GET and POST methods?

Tags: reactjs, http, post, get, postman

I have created a webpage using ReactJS. When I called my web URL in postman using the GET method, I got my HTML page as a response. But when I changed this method to POST, then got an error(404 Not Found). Can I make my URL available in the POST method too? Is this possible?

Comment: Getting a Website of the Type GET Method.

Comment: No, you can't use GET and POST methods for the same URL. You must pick either of them.

Comment: Could you elaborate the situation? As far as I can tell , in both the requests , you  can choose to send the same page if you want, not sure what the issue is?(you would have too handle both types of requests and return HTML/JSON accordingly)

Comment: Could you add your postman definition

Comment: I had run my react project in my local system. Then called my home page URL "http://localhost:3000/home" using GET and POST method through postman. I am getting the response when using the GET method. I want to get the response both in GET and POST methods. I'm able to do it in NodeJs by handling both types of requests separately. But how can I do it in ReactJs?